# Multiple Styled Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a styled Google Map V3 on my contact page http://www.liebekuchen.co.uk/talk-to-us/ which works okay bar a few issues with sprite image display, however I need to add this JSON to two separate maps on my showrooms page http://www.liebekuchen.co.uk/kitchen-showrooms/ how do I add styling to multiple maps with different locations? JS called in page head;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    // V3 map

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng('51.4525368','0.2481994');


        var mapOptions = {

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng('51.4600368','0.0781994'),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scrollwheel:false

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("head-office-map"), mapOptions);


      var styles = [
      map styles here...
        ]
      }
    ];


    map.setOptions({styles: styles});

    var contentString = "";

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,

    });

    var $image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("../images/icons/LK-mapicon.png",
    // size
    new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
    // origin
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // anchor
    new google.maps.Point(25, 50));

    var $shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("../images/icons/LK-mapicon-shadow.png",
    // size
    new google.maps.Size(65, 39),
    // origin
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // anchor
    new google.maps.Point(25, 50));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        clickable: false,
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Liebe Kuchen Head Office",
        icon:$image,
        shadow:$shadow
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });


});
```

Comment: "however I need to add this JSON to two separate maps" - which JSON? I don't see any JSON in your code?

Comment: Sorry bit misleading and maybe ill informed. The JSON I believed was the script generated when I created the styled map through the wizard, i.e the map styles and marker styles? I removed the style script as it was quite long and not necessary for this question. I just need to be able to add a variation of this script to two maps on a separate page (The JS is called in the header so thats not my issue) its adapting the code to include different maps contained in different divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same javascript to multiple pages, create an external file that just defines that code (the map style) and include it in all maps that need it.  (Not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mapstyle.js"></script>
```

Where "mapstyle.js" would contain:

```
  var styles = [
  map styles here...
    ]
  }
];
```